# How to filter a specific value in a column data type array in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table x of the following template:
Column1(integer), column2(array)

Where array is a tuple of type: (2.a: bla bla, 2.b: bla bla)

I need to select only the lines in sql where the array holds some tuple where 2.b is of some value. Can it be done with an sql query? How?

- I don't have the possibility to change the architecture of the table. I know it is an abuse of how to work with sql based DB's

I am new to sql. I don't know how to create sql functions or such

Comment: Hey could you please share the DDL of the table, if I am not wrong SQL Server currently doesn't support array data types. Might be the data is stored as JSON and if so this could be of [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: AFAIK, Sql server has no array  data type.

Comment: I think you can use `JSON_VALUE` to solve your problem. 
`SELECT *
FROM tableX
WHERE JSON_VALUE(columnName, '$."2.b"') = 'your_value';`

Comment: What RDBMs Are you working with?